# How to ignore a Android build variant in Azure build pipeline?

Tags: android, azure, gradle

I ran into a bit of an issue today with our Android application and Azure Pipelines today. When in the office, we all use Windows machines for development. Today, I was using my Macbook Pro to do a quick bug fix and push it up to Azure. In our `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\android_keystore\\app_keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'app'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

On our PCs, we all have the `app_keystore.jks` file in that directory and this obviously works fine for Windows computers and for our Azure Build Pipeline. But you can see the issue of how this will not work with macOS because there is no C drive.

My first thought was to add another signing config aptly named `dev_macos` and corresponding  build variant to use exclusively on macOS: `~\\android_keystore\\app_keystore.jks` which works when building and signing locally in Android Studio; however, when we try and run our build pipeline on Azure DevOps, we get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigning'.
> Keystore file 'C:\agent_android\_work\1\s\app\~\android_keystore\app_keystore.jks' not found for signing config 'dev_macos'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It took a little bit to find the optimal solution to this that made the most sense. What we ended up doing was add a `variantFilter` in our app's `build.gradle`. This allows the build variant to be ignored when being built on Azure and thus, get past the error. It has the added bonus of not wasting time in the pipeline as the only difference with the build variant is utilizing that different signing config with the alternate keystore path. Here's the all of the code we added:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\android_keystore\\app_keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'app'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }

        mac {
            storeFile file('~\\android_keystore\\app_keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'app'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }

    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.name == "debug_mac") {
            setIgnore(true)
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug_mac {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.mac
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly and I hope helps someone out if they come across the same issue.